# PHP to display more columns of a SQL row on new page, then saving it

Tags: php, mysql, get, file-get-contents, str-replace

Any help here would be incredible:
Desired workflow: User browses through sql rows (page 1), only selective data is displayed. After clicking on a row it routs (script on Page 2) to a page (Page 3) that shows all the data for that row. And that page is saved in the directory.

Page 1 (index.php)

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE id
        BETWEEN 1 AND 200 order by RAND() LIMIT 50";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
?>
<?php
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $id = $data['id'];
    $title = $data['title'];
?>
    <li onclick="location.href='create_page.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>';">
        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
    </li>
<?php
endwhile;
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Page 2 (create_page.php)

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$_GET['id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE id=$_GET[id]";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $id = $data['id'];
    $author = $data['author'];
    $title = $data['title'];
    $page_path = $data['page_path'];
    if(is_null($page_path)){$page_path = "#";}
    $data2 = file_get_contents("single-page.php");
    $data2 = str_replace($title2, $title, $data2);
    $data2 = str_replace($author2, $author, $data2);

    file_put_contents($page_path, $data2);

endwhile;
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Page 3 (single-page.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <?php echo $title2; ?>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $title2; ?>
        <?php echo $author2; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

After user clicks on row the script begins, but freezes up (i checked and page source is blank in browser). The parameter 'ID' is in the url (`. . .php?id= . .`), but nothing after that. 'page_path' is a column from sql table (unique to each row) and directs where the page is to be saved. id is a unique auto_num column. Also, file and folder permissions are all 777.

Thank you in advance!

Alternative method:

```
<?php
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>
Your page content bla bla bla bla ...

<?php
 echo '1';

 // Get the content that is in the buffer and put it             
In your file //
file_put_contents('yourpage.html',  
ob_get_contents());
 ?>
```

Comment: try to print errors like mysqli_query('----') or die('query not executed').And in the 2nd page the GET[id]-->change to GET['id']

Comment: I get a syntax error in dreamweaver when I change [id] to ['id']

Answer (score 0):

your problem, seems like to be here

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE id=$_GET[id]";
```

`$_GET[id]` is empty, your variable is `$_GET['id']`

just, test this code in page 2

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {  //check if $_GET['id'] is a number
  $id=$_GET['id'];


  include("db.php");
  $query="SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE id=$id";
echo $query;  //show the query.
  $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $id = $data['id'];
    $author = $data['author'];
    $title = $data['title'];
    $page_path = $data['page_path'];
echo "id=".$id." author=".$author." title=".$title." page_path=".$page_path;
//show your variables.
    if(is_null($page_path)){$page_path = "#";}

if(is_file($page_path)){
        $data2 = file_get_contents("single-page.php");
        $data2 = str_replace($title2, $title, $data2);
        $data2 = str_replace($author2, $author, $data2);

        file_put_contents($page_path, $data2);
     }
else
echo "file".$page_path." doesnt exist :(";
  endwhile;
  mysqli_close($connection);
  }else echo "ID is not numeric";
 }else echo "error on ID data";
```

Comment: I get a syntax error in dreamweaver . . line 4 - when defining id it doesn't like having the 'id'. Script doesn't run nor the error you added report. good idea re the error echos though I need to change my thinking about including them. any more suggestions? very grateful for your time.

Comment: @buzrw check now, i added is_numeric condition.

Comment: They are already all numbers. I made suggested changes, I also read that the file path needed to be server local not http, as I'm using Linux. Still not working, I adjusted code to put the tags in brackets on the page its writing to. I edited the code above to what I am currently using. Also when I run this code and I view source of the page it freezes running I get this: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Comment: here's an example of a $page_path value  single-pages/1-trebort-ouzzub-coatomer-proteinomplexubunit-gamma.php

Comment: ok, let us concentrate in page 2... what happend when you put in your browser localhost/path_to_file/create_page.php?id=1? ... did it show something?

Comment: Nothing, white screen. Source code shows new empty page created. I'm actually wondering if I need to use output buffering? What do you think?remember  goal here to save the page with the current output: I will add code to the above, I won't be able to try it until later today but if you should see it let me know what you think?

Comment: great, i thought that you forgot this question... now accept my solution, you know, i like to expand my reputation :P